# How do I knit r markdown into pdf or html with packages?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have been working with r markdown for a project. I used different packages within the markdown, which work in r studio since I have the package downloaded. However when I tried to knit the markdown into pdf or html, it gave me an error, I am assuming because those commands require a package. How do I fix this so I can successfully knit my project?

```
ggplot(data=formulation.df, aes(x= formulation, y= temps)) + geom_boxplot(col="red", fill="blue") + xlab("Formlation") + ylab("Temperature") + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a code chunk somewhere that has `library(ggplot2)`? It's often cumstomary to have a "setup" chunk at the start of your document with `include=FALSE` where you load all your packages.

Comment: @Becca: these might help https://r4ds.had.co.nz/r-markdown.html & http://zevross.com/blog/2017/06/19/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-images-and-figures-in-r-markdown-documents/

Comment: Thank you, I had just forgotten to add the code to load the packages in the markdown file. It works now :)